# CSS loading is slow on heroku hosted site

Tags: heroku, clojure, noir

I am using heroku to host a clojure app using noir. Its the free account with one web dyno.

I have trouble in that the content of the site load, however the CSS doesnt load. On couple of refreshes it will load back properly. However if I was to again clear the browsers cache, and refresh, the same behavior is observed.

Thus all new users have a terrible experience, where only the raw conentent shows up the first time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Has anyone other than you had this issue? I highly doubt this has anything to do with Heroku or your code. Sounds like your web browser has done wonky.

Comment: Nope everyone using it was having it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a server on EC2 and then serving the static resources using nginx. I am not sure how I would do that on heroku.